# How to prevent access to subdomain without htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I want to create a subdomain to be used as a staging environment. I don't want it to be publicly accessible and I want to avoid using htaccess. (e.g. dev.example.com)

The subdomain should be restricted to certain IP addresses, which will be stored in a MySQL table and regularly updated. (I'm running PHP 5.6/Apache/Centos 7)

What is the best way to do this?

I could add a PHP check for `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in my config, however, images and javascript files would still be publicly accessible.

Comment: _“however, images and javascript files would still be publicly accessible”_ - well then you would have to proxy all requests for those through a PHP script as well ... _“What is the best way to do this?”_ - to dynamically create the necessary htaccess, when your database content is updated ...

Comment: dynamically creating the necessary htaccess file seems like the best solution

Answer (score 0):

What's your reasoning for not wanting a htaccess file?

The htaccess files provide an extension to the central configuration file for the httpd - anything which goes in there can go in a <directory> or <location> block in the httpd.conf or vhost configuration (and vice versa).

> which will be stored in a MySQL table

Apache won't read its config directly from MySQL. Nor will lots of other things you might use to manage access (e.g. a second webserver instance on a different port). While I suppose you could deploy squid as a reverse proxy with a url-rewriter which reads from the database, this looks like a lot of work.

Relying on IP addresses for authentication is generally considered a bad idea in the first place.

I would recommend either using [client certs](https://stuff-things.net/2015/09/28/configuring-apache-for-ssl-client-certificate-authentication/) or restrict the access to 127.0.0.1 and connect with an ssh tunnel.

Comment: I didn't want to use htaccess since the permitted IP addresses will be changing regularly

Comment: Yet another reason NOT to base authentication on IP addresses. OTOH you can change an htaccess file at any time and the webserver should honour the new version - but change the main config and you need to restart.